# Language translation in jquery date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I include both language translation and changeMonth and changeYear options together in jquery date picker. For that I used the below code
For Language translation

```
$(this).datepicker($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
```

For ChangeYear

```
$( this ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
```

I want to run these two in a single datepicker box.Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source the regional is an object with options so this should work:

```
$(this).datepicker($.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional['fr'], {
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way (see this JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kp8Nq/).
You can change the localization option instead of creating a new datepicker:

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
     $("#datepicker").datepicker("option",
        $.datepicker.regional["fr"]);

    $("#locale").change(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("option",
        $.datepicker.regional[$(this).val()]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would let the user decide, if you have a multi-national website:

See: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Localize calendar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.ui.datepicker-ar.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.ui.datepicker-he.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.ui.datepicker-zh-TW.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
    $( "#locale" ).change(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option",
        $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" />&nbsp;
  <select id="locale">
    <option value="ar">Arabic (‫(العربية</option>
    <option value="zh-TW">Chinese Traditional (繁體中文)</option>
    <option value="">English</option>
    <option value="fr" selected="selected">French (Français)</option>
    <option value="he">Hebrew (‫(עברית</option>
  </select></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) used this syntax: `$( selector ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );`  but it didn't work for me. The above with the `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option",...` did work.